# webbrowser encoding problem

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using a `WebBrowser` control in my project. My code example is below:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("Web Site goes here");
```

The web browser is navigating the Google website, however I can not see the Turkish characters.

Therefore I use:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Encoding = "UTF-8"
```

However the problem still continues. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Does the site work when you navigate to it from some other external browser?

Comment: Check the charset in the meta tag of the page is the same

Comment: darin: yes , alleo: I do the checking, it is also utf-8

Answer (score 4):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.webBrowser1.DocumentStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
string source = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

or you can try "iso-8859-9" for encoding.
this should do it.

Comment: ISO-8859-9 is for Turkish only. Then, he won't be able to show English characters.

Comment: @r3st0r3 So he has to parse the beginning of the document, if there is a "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />" block he can use the value of "charset" field as the required encoding scheme. Problem?

Answer (score 2):

This was really helpful.

I was stuck with this for a while and managed to get my code to work

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(urlfile, FileMode.Create))
                        {

                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                sw.Write(datasetHtmlreplacements);
                                sw.Close();
                            }
                        }
```