# Strange characters appear when using WPF webbrowser, and HTML with italic tag and arabic text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, internationalization

I cannot figure this one but I have made a simple demo below. When this page is viewed in IE or Edge it renders properly. I have tried different encodings like utf-16, Windows-1252 but did not work. Looks like an issue with WebBrowser control to me. Can someone figure this out ?

**ArabicPage.html**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><i>اتفاقية</i></p>
    <p>اتفاقية</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**LayoutTest.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.LayoutTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Yellow"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded"
    Title="LayoutTest">
    <WebBrowser x:Name="MyWebBrowser" Margin="20,5,0,5"/>
</Page>
```

**LayoutTest.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class LayoutTest : Page
    {
        public LayoutTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string dirPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDi‌rectory;
            string fileName = "ArabicPage.html";
            string filename = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(dirPath, fileName));
            string content = File.ReadAllText(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
            MyWebBrowser.NavigateToString(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Without italic tag it renders properly:

[image: Arabic without italic tag]

Render in Edge browser:

[image: Arabic rendered in Edge]

Update:

I have tested this with UWP webview and it works properly there.

Comment: see updated description

Comment: Wonder if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281137/webbrowser-encoding-problem

Comment: @Alex i  have played around with different encodings none worked, UTF-8 and 16 should work anyway but maybe it's nothing to do with encoding  ? Interestingly I have tested this in UWP webview and it works fine

Comment: This answer talks about loading the URL and then doing a refresh: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12285309/177416

Comment: You need to label the html `lang` as arabic, of your type, not `en`

Comment: Also, an empty title is not going to be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid it by using a font that properly supports Arabic characters, as an example Tahoma:

```
<html lang="ar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style = "font-family:Tahoma,serif">
    <p><i style = "font-size:26px;">اتفاقية</i></p>
    <p style = "font-size:26px;">اتفاقية</p>
</body>
</html>
```

By default the font in windows 10 is Segoe UI. It seems that it is a Windows 10 issue more [details from microsoft here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3083806/why-does-some-text-display-with-square-boxes-in-some-apps-on-windows-1).

**EDIT:**

[Reply to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678871/strange-characters-appear-when-using-wpf-webbrowser-and-html-with-italic-tag-an#comment109215274_61735059)

In fact you can see at windows 10 settings/fonts page (filter by Arabic), that `Segoe UI` font has a separate italic face font from the Regular face, on the opposite `Tahoma` italic is included in the regular face. Although when I tried an Arabic word sample in this settings with `Segoe UI` as a selected font it was surprisingly properly rendering characters with all the font styles available.

[image]

Comment: you are right this font make it work, how did you find this out, why it does not work when font is not specified, what is actually happening under the hood ?

Comment: @IronHide I don't know exactly what is going on under the hood but i have provided a link in the answer that contains some details, i believe you are using windows10 since the same code that showing square instead of Arabic characters on windows 10 will run just fine on windows7.

Comment: You have labeled the html for the page as being in English, not Arabic.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts thanks I have edited, note: with `lang="ar"` only issue persist.

Comment: I realise that will not alter the display, unless there are strong latin characters present, but in production, this will mislead search engines, and assistive technologies, such as screen readers.

Comment: @Cfun thank you for the link, looks like it's related, but I am wondering why italics tag <i> is the cause of the issue ? Perhaps <i> is converted to a font that does not support arabic under the hood ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer about that, but if my solution answers your question please accept it.